# Is "than it." grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

For example, something like

> Does this desktop perform better than laptops that are more expensive than it?

Comment: Why do you need the words *than it* at all?

Comment: It uses 'than' twice and is a bit cumbersome. *Does this desktop perform better than more expensive laptops?*

Comment: Arguably grammatically correct, but will possibly lose half a mark for style at Advanced Level.